# How to apply Eclipse Kepler settings to Netbeans 8.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-plugin, migration

I want to migrate from **Eclipse Kepler** to **Netbeans 8.0**. Because of i think Netbeans is more better than Eclipse. Then i want to do this:

1. Copy the all of plugins and softwares that installed on **Eclipse** to **Netbeans**
2. Apply all of Eclipse shortcuts to Netbeans

Is it possible?

Comment: You want all eclipse plugins and shortcuts in netbeans? Why do you think netbean is better than Eclipse?

Comment: I'm .NET Developer and currently want to start Java EE, Spring and Hibernate. But the Eclipse in comparison with Visual Studio is very bad and weak. Then i think that Netbeans is more better and easy to use than Eclipse.

Comment: And the another reason is the UI of IDE is very important to me

Comment: And i think Eclipse is error full than Netbeans. I mean for example when i want to run a very simple web application on Eclipse, i should see more errors, but Netbeans automatically do that without any error like the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The plug-ins for the two are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Apply all of Eclipse shortcuts to Netbeans

A: There a built-in keymap called "Eclipse" in NetBeans Options|KeyMap

If you want to reuse the Java Formatting settings have a look at http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50877/eclipse-code-formatter-for-java